# Is it possible to modify the parametric texture of a displacement modifier to create a progressive geometry?

Tags: modifiers

For example (see image 1), I'm using a parametric WOOD TEXTURE and DISPLACEMENT MODIFIER on a subdivided plane to create this object. But I want the geometry (i.e. the wave's amplitude) to progressively increase or decrease (from 0.0 to 1.0, for example).
[image: image 1]
image 1

I understand how to smoothly modulate the waves' height using a VERTEX GROUP (see image 2). 
[image: image 2]
image 2

But now I want the space between the waves (or amplitude) to progressively change, as represented in this example (see image 3) using ARRAY planes and a modifier object to progressively modulate the X and Y values of the planes.
[image: image 3]